# How to log the element with the EventListener instead of its children using e.target in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, event-listener

I have an li element with a click EventListener and I want to have the li element logged using e.target, however if I click in anything that is inside the li, it logs that instead of the li with the actual EventListener on it. How can I make it so that only the li/Element with the EventListener is the logged?

Here is a sandbox of the code: https://codesandbox.io/embed/romantic-noether-gdjjv?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

The desired result is that it logs the li regardless of where I click in it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must Use `e.currentTarget` instead of `e.target`.

Comment: your welcome. it's good to mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your logs to as follows

`const handleClick = (e) => { console.log(e.currentTarget); };`

Comment: Thanks.. You may upvote and accept this as answer